# How can I cut an image along Paths in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi I would like to "cut" an image into multiple parts using Illustrator Paths. 
Like a clipping mask, but with a lot of different parts and in one step. Or in one process, but not 100 clipping mask. One after the other. If this is not possible with Illustrator, any other software would be great.

Comment: No its not possible to clip or pretty much do anything useful for raster images in illustrator. Unless your willing to copy the image several times.

Comment: You need to define what "image" means -- a raster or vector image? It *may* be possible.

Comment: I want to cut a raster image with vector paths. I know it is not the usual way one does things. I know that PS is primary for raster and AI is primary for paths. What I want is a way I can cut raster images along vector paths. I can cut it in PS, step by step, but I would like to find a way where I can load a raster image overlay it with multiple paths and then cut the image along these paths. If this is impossible or unpraticable in AI, maybe there is other software or addons that can achieve this. I hope I clarified. I like the compound path solution, but it does not solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a clipping mask of more than one shape you have to make a compound path of all of your shapes, Once all of your shapes are a 1 compound path the clipping mask will interpret it as all part of the same shape
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That looks like I want. But can I make them seperate objects after cutting it ? So I can only move one cut/part

Comment: depends on what  you want to happen to the inside. Do you want it to "take the image with him" or to got to another part of the background image

Comment: I want the "inside" (image part). This should independet objects.

Comment: Of each "square" (if we use my example) separately?

Comment: Yes. But since it is a clipping mask. Everything that is inside that square.

Comment: then no - you can only move the entire group of "squares"  or with the direct selection tool only one square but what's inside it will change according to the background

Comment: you could separate the group and deal with each clip individual by going to `object > Flatten Transparency` -- this will slice your image into smaller parts (check the links panel)

Comment: Thanks ! This sounds like what I want. I did ungroup and tried to do Object>Flatten Trans. But it does not have any effect on the clipping mask. I selected the whole clipping mask with (V) and just one with (A) and did Flatten Trans, but it did not flatten that clipping.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do actually is contradictory. And you can't do it in one step. If you import 1 image into Illustrator you cannot have different parts of one image behave as separate independent images. You are making this harder than it needs to be. Just crop your image in Photoshop 3 times for instance. Make each crop approximate the area you want to reveal in Illustrator in each clipping path. Save each crop as a separate image and them import each one into its own clipping path in Illustrator. It is much easier and flexible to do it this way. You can move each one around seperately and tweek the clipping paths separately to show exactly what you want. The problem would be if you have alot of pieces. Here I just used an example of 3. I would be more work, but this is the way to do this. If I had alot of this to do I would use Indesign. But you still have to "pre-crop" the image so you can have the pieces you want to place in your document.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I described what I am looking for exactly in a comment to my question above